# Add local Gradle source module by absolute path

Tags: gradle, include, absolute

I want to add a subproject to my Gradle project. The project is located *somewhere* on my hard disk drive, for example:

```
/A/Path/to/a/ProjectA
/Another/Path/to/another/ProjectB
```

What I want to achieve is to use ProjectB as a source module within Project A. However, all my attempts to do this so far - either by adding `include /Another/Path/to/another/ProjectB` or by adding `include ':ProjectB'; project(':ProjectB').projectDir = ...` in settings.gradle - just failed. Apparently, Gradle is not able to find the project.

How can I add ProjectB as a dependency without moving it from it's location?

Comment: in general, the solution you proposed (using settings.gradle) works great. Did you add then the :ProjectB dependency into ProjectA (build.gradle)?

Answer (score 1):

Using Gradle 3.4.1, the following works for me (full example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_51649701)):

```
include 'app', 'common'

def MY_PATH = '/Users/johndoe/foo'
assert new File("$MY_PATH/random/path/common").exists()

project(':common').projectDir = new File("$MY_PATH/random/path/common")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.
Turns out I've made several mistakes:

1. Adding the project to the built was dependent on the value of an environment variable. I replaced that with a property within gradle.properties.
2. I tested this by running the settings.gradle usind IntelliJ. I mistakingly expected this to work, but it didn't
3. I did not add the project as a dependency to the build.gradle file of the parent project.

It works now. Thank you all again!